# sitecore user domain and roles returning null

Tags: authentication, sitecore, sitecore6

I have a sitecore setup with a front end login page for extranet users to access restricted pages within the site.

Extranet users are currently being logged in with the persistence flag equal ture

```
global::Sitecore.Security.Domains.Domain domain = global::Sitecore.Context.Domain;
var isLogginedIn = AuthenticationManager.Login(domain + @"\" + email, password, true);
```

This works successfully and the context is set correctly.

Below is output from immediate window after login within the same request.

```
global::Sitecore.Context.User.Domain
extranet

global::Sitecore.Context.User.Roles.Count()
1

global::Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated()
true
```

After the user is logged in the user is redirected to the page they wanted to access.

Below is output form immediate window on any subsequent requests

```
global::Sitecore.Context.User.Domain
null

global::Sitecore.Context.User.Roles.Count()
0

global::Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated()
true
```

Anyone have any ideas why I might lose some context items on subsequent requests?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create your own login page for Sitecore. In this case you may try to start `logginging` pipeline **instead of** calling `AuthenticationManager.Login` method:

```
var loggingInArgs = new LoggingInArgs
{
    Username = userName,
    Password = password,
    StartUrl = startUrl
};

Pipeline.Start("loggingin", loggingInArgs);
bool isLogginedIn = loggingInArgs.Success;
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick response but I am unable to log in using that method.

I get the following messages:

`You do not have access to the system. If you think this is wrong, please contact the system administrator.\n\nYour login attempt was not successful. Please try again.\n\nYou do not have access to the system. If you think this is wrong, please contact the system administrator.\n\n`

As far as I understood the log in pipeline is only for back end access. This is a login page for a website user on the extranet domain.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a patch to hide this problem rather than a proper solution but I will post anyone just in case it triggers anyone else to have any further ideas about this.

I am calling the following code during a custom pipeline

```
if (user.Domain == null && user.IsAuthenticated)
{
   var domainUser = string.Format(@"extranet\{0}", user.LocalName);
   var membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(domainUser);

   if (membershipUser != null)
   {
      AuthenticationManager.Login(domainUser, membershipUser.GetPassword(), true);
   }
}
```

After this is called the user has domain and roles correctly set. Strangely, all other requests after this have a correctly set user.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this exact issue where Domain is null and Roles is empty.
The cause was that i used a asp:Login control to log the user in. When i replaced this with a standard Text, Password and Button controls, the problem disappeared.